# How to configure IPsec (strongswan) interface, so that only assigned interface gets virtual ip?

Tags: networking, ipsec, strongswan, bug

I have already used this configuration a bunch of times and I haven't had this problem before. Basically I establish the tunnel connection, but after connecting (with `swanctl --initiate --child ch_vti0 --ike ch_vti0`)
I get my virtual ip assigned on the appropriate interface `vti0`, but also I have the same ip assigned on my main interface `enp2s0` (The one connected to the internet)

From the journal with extended debugging options I get the following (shortened for the sake of brevity):

```
юли 29 09:33:45 malz charon-custom[21535]: 12[IKE] installing new virtual IP 172.13.14.3
...
юли 29 09:33:45 malz charon-custom[21535]: 12[KNL] virtual IP 172.13.14.3 installed on enp2s0
...
юли 29 09:33:45 malz charon-custom[21535]: 11[KNL] adding policy 192.168.122.0/24 === 172.13.14.3/32 in (mark 42/0xffffffff) [priority 371327, refcount 1]
...
юли 29 09:33:45 malz charon-custom[21535]: 11[KNL] using host 172.13.14.3
...
юли 29 09:33:45 malz charon-custom[21535]: 11[KNL] installing route: 192.168.122.0/24 via 10.3.218.62 src 172.13.14.3 dev enp2s0
...
юли 29 09:33:45 malz charon-custom[21535]: 11[IKE] CHILD_SA ch_vti0{1} established with SPIs cbaeec67_i c450a827_o and TS 172.13.14.3/32 === 192.168.122.0/24
...
юли 29 09:33:45 malz charon-custom[21535]: 16[KNL] 172.13.14.3 appeared on vti0
```

So basically I make the connection and immediately my main interface enp2s0 gets the virtual ip and after that the other interface vti0 gets the ip.

Side note: I know I can work around the issue by just deleting the route through the main interface, but my goal is to stop the assignment 
altogether.

My swanctl.conf  (Initiator):

```
connections {
   ch_vti0 {
      send_cert = always
      encap = yes
      vips = 0.0.0.0
      remote_addrs = 10.3.218.62
      local {
         round = 1
         id = 10.3.72.29
         auth = psk
         certs = 
       }
      remote {
         auth = psk
         id = 10.3.218.62
         certs = 
       }
      children {
        ch_vti0 { 
            updown = /usr/local/etc/swanctl/updown.sh 0
            mark_in = 42 
            mark_out = 42 
            remote_ts = 192.168.122.2/24
            local_ts = dynamic
            inactivity = 300s
            mode = tunnel
            esp_proposals =  3des-sha1-modp2048
         }
      }
      version = 1 
      proposals =  des-md5-modp768, des-md5-modp1024, des-md5-modp1536
   }  }
secrets {
        eap-xauth {
        eap_id = test1
        id = test1
        secret = password
   }
        xauth-local {
        id = test1
        secret = password
        }
        ike-sec {
        id = %any
        secret = test
        }
        ike-local {
        id = 10.3.72.29
        secret = test
        }
}
```

The servers setup (responder):

```
connections {
   ch_vti0 {
      send_cert = always
      encap = yes
      pools = pools_users
      #aggressive = yes
      local {
         round = 1
         id = 10.3.218.62
         auth = psk
         certs = 
       }
      remote {
         auth = psk
         id = %any
         certs = 
       }
      children {
        ch_vti0 { 
            local_ts = 192.168.122.2/24
            inactivity = 120s
            mode = tunnel
            esp_proposals =  3des-sha1-modp2048
         }
      }
      version = 0
      proposals =  des-md5-modp768, des-md5-modp1024, des-md5-modp1536
   }  }
pools {
        pools_users {
                addrs = 172.13.14.2/24
        }
}
secrets {
        eap-xauth {
        eap_id = test1
        id = test1
        secret = password
   }
        xauth-local {
        id = test1
        secret = password
        }
        ike-sec {
        id = %any
        secret = test
        }
        ike-local {
        id = 10.3.218.62
        secret = test
        }
}
```

I also know that I can use the strongswan charon parameters:

```
# install_virtual_ip_on = vti0
# interfaces_use = vti0
# interfaces_ignore = enp2s0
```

But if I do the process can not progress as if it needs to use the enp2s0 interface. Has anyone else ever had this issue ? Any suggestions are welcome.

Also I am using strongSwan 5.7.2, Linux 4.18.0-25-generic.

About the updown script it really doesn't matter, because I get the same error if I do the same configuration without the script.

Comment: What version of the strongswan do you use? I'll try to reproduce this issue in the lab.

Comment: Also, paste the content of `/usr/local/etc/swanctl/updown.sh` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally found a way to do correct this. The problem as I said was that the wrong interface was used on top of the correct interface, I haven't figured out why, but the workaround I did find I believe is good enough.
In the strongswan.conf (usually in /etc/strongswan.conf or /usr/local/etc/strongswan.conf) set the variable 
 `install_routes = no`  , its yes by default.
From the StrongSwan docs the variable is:

```
Install routes into a separate routing table for established IPsec tunnels. If disabled a more efficient lookup for source and next-hop addresses is used since 5.5.2.
```

So by doing this I forbid the creating of table 220 and addition of routes to it. Instead it configures the correct route on it's own by checking which interface has a route to the particular IP.

As already mentioned using the variables may also solve your problem.

```
# install_virtual_ip_on = vti0
# interfaces_use = vti0
# interfaces_ignore = enp2s0
```

strongswan.conf:

```
charon {
        install_routes = no
        load_modular = yes
        plugins {
                include strongswan.d/charon/*.conf
        }
include strongswan.d/*.conf
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need add only `install_virtual_ip_on = vti0` option to solve your issue.

**Don't touch** the `interfaces_use` and `interfaces_ignore` options.

Comment: I have tried that, but the outcome is the same. The interface vti0 gets its ip that is not the problem, the problem is that the other interface enp2s0 also gets it.

Comment: FYI if you are still trying to reproduce, I updated to StrongSwan 5.8.0 and the issue still remains.

Comment: Ok. I'll check it tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for this thread : it saved my day. *install_virtual_ip_on* is indeed the key. And of course, do not forget to restart strongswan using service strongswan restart (took me a couple of hours to figure out that) :-(